# How to return a value from a function that is generated from a parse query within the function?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, completionhandler

Problem:  when I call the below function within my ViewController tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I get nil, but I need to set the generated object to a PFObject variable called rankObject that I declared globally in my ViewController.  I've tried a lot of things, including completion handlers, and am still stuck.  How would I accomplish this task?

```
func getOrMakeRankRelations(sound: PFObject) {
    var rankRelation = sound.relationForKey("userRanks")
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
    var relationQuery = rankRelation.query()
    relationQuery?.whereKey("user", equalTo: currentUser)
    relationQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (theObject: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (theObject?.isEmpty == true) {
            println("Rank object is empty")

            //Make Ranking PFObject
            var ranking = PFObject(className: "Ranking")
            ranking["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()!
            ranking["Rank"] = 0

            //Upload ranking to Parse
            ranking.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (saved: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if saved {
                    println("Saved ranking")

                    //Add relation between sound and ranking
                    rankRelation.addObject(ranking)
                    sound.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (saved: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                        if saved {
                            println("Saved relation")
                            var theObject = (theObject![0] as? PFObject)!
                            self.rankObject = theObject //////////NOTE:  the variable saves while in this closure /////////////
                        } else {
                            println("Relation not saved :(")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    println(error)
                }
            }
        } else {
            var theObject = (theObject![0] as? PFObject)!
            self.rankObject = theObject  //////////NOTE:  the variable also saves while in this closure /////////////
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I call the function in tableView:

```
getOrMakeRankRelation(sound)
```

Comment: In xcode, you can place your cursor on `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`, right click, and select "Jump to definition".  What you'll see is how parse declares that asynchronous function to take a block param.  You can (should do the same with your getOrMakeRankRelation function.  Its return value is worthless because the real work gets done after it returns.    It needs a completion block of its own.

Comment: And before you call it from cellForRowAtIndexPath, consider that it will fire off a zillion network requests as the user scrolls.  To serve a table, you need an array data source.  Before asking the network for data, see if its in your local array.  After asking the network for something, put it in your local array.  In this sense, your data source is a local cache for objects retrieved from parse.

Comment: yeah, definitely don't save things from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: try saving and fetching in another controller that your viewcontroller talks to.

Comment: @danh, will you provide code on how I would implement your first comment?  I find it perplexing that I have another very similar function that doesn't have a completion block and works fine storing values in an array outside the function.  Also, note taken on your 2nd comment, I will be modifying the function accordingly, thanks.

Comment: I would have made those comments an answer, but it would have required that I compromise on my stubborn refusal to learn Swift.  Would objective-c be useful to you?

Comment: @danh, yes it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not dealing with the specifics of the asynch call, just the fact that it is asynchronous, in Objective-C (and Swift) we declare a function to take at least two parameters: whatever is needed to parameterize the remote request, and a block to run when the request completes.

Reading your code, I'd also advise breaking the get and the create part into their own functions, just to remain sane, so...

```
- (void)getOrCreateRankForSound:(PFObject *)sound completion:(void (^)(PFObject *, NSError *))completion {

    [self getRankForSound:sound completion:^(PFObject *rank, NSError *error) {
        if (!rank && !error) {  // there's no rank, and no error either, so we must create one

            [self createRankForSound:sound completion:^(PFObject *rank, NSError *error) {
                completion(rank, error);
            }];

        } else {
            completion(rank, error);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)createRankForSound:(PFObject *)sound completion:(void (^)(PFObject *, NSError *))completion {

    // build a PFObject rank for the sound, then save it and tell our
    // caller what happened by invoking the completion block
    // ...
    [newlyCreatedRank saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        return (success)? completion(newlyCreatedRank, nil) : completion(nil, error);
    }];
}
```

Now your cellForRowAtIndexPath can safely call this method, because it caches the results.

```
// pseudo code in cellForRowAtIndexPath
PFObject *sound = self.myDatasourceArray[indexPath.row];

// we want to change some cell subview to present the rank object

// don't make network requests in this method without caching the result
// assume we have a dictionary of rank objects indexed by the sound object id to which they correspond
PFObject *rank = self.ranksForSound[sound.objectId];
if (rank) {
    // no need to make a network request, use the rank, presumably to update the cell
    cell.rankLabel.text = // some function of rank
} else {
    // we need to make a network request, put a placeholder value in the cell and call our function
    cell.rankLabel.text = // some placeholder value
    [self getOrCreateRankForSound:sound completion:^(PFObject *rank, NSError *error) {
        // this is important, the cell might have scrolled away by the time this block runs
        // don't alter the cell directly, just reload it.  cellForRowAtIndexPath will
        // get called again, but now the cache will be primed
        if (!error) {
            [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]];
        }
    }];
}
// configure other parts of the cell
return cell;
```

Comment: it works!!!!!  I successfully migrated your Objective C code to Swift and it's functioning well.  You saved my bacon on this one, thank you!